# Geoserver raster with external SLD

Tags: geoserver, wms

I want to use an external SLD (hosted in my server) for symbolizing a raster in Geoserver.

The SLD below works if used as default style in Geoserver. If I copy it (changing some colors) and put outside Geoserver, save as SLD (or XML), and call the GetMap with SLD=https://my_server/mySLD.sld the map I get is still with the 'default, Geoserver' style

```
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>my_schema:my_layer</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
               <Rule>
                    <RasterSymbolizer>
                        <Geometry>
                           <PropertyName>GRAY_INDEX</PropertyName>
                        </Geometry>
                        <Opacity>1</Opacity>
                        <ColorMap>
                           <ColorMapEntry color="#E69800" label="1" opacity="0.0" quantity="0.0"/>                     
                            <ColorMapEntry color="#1b4bde" label="Building" opacity="1.0" quantity="1.0"/>
                            <ColorMapEntry color="#bcbcbc" label="Ground cover" opacity="1.0" quantity="2.0"/>
                                 
                    </ColorMap>
       </RasterSymbolizer>
      </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>    
  </StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

shortly, WMS call would be like this (also tried withou STYLES param)
`https://my_geoserver_url/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=my_schema:my_layer&STYLES=&SLD=https://my_server/my_sld.sld&transparent=true&bbox=...&format=image/png`

I did this for dynamic filtering in vectorial data and all good (SLDs are created dynamically via PHP), so I am wondering if the problem is that with RASTER data is not possible

Comment: You don't need `styles=` which gives you the default if you specify a style with `SLD=some url`.  I know geoserver is forgiving with syntax, but strictly speaking `transparent=true&` should give no transparency, because the allowed vales are `TRUE|FALSE` case sensitive and the default is FALSE

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to operate in [library mode](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/working.html#library-mode):

> Style lookup in library mode operates as follows:
>
> - For each layer in the layers list, the applied style is either a named style specified in the styles list (if present), or the layerdefault style
> - For a named style, if the external style document has a `<NamedLayer>...<UserStyle>` with matching layer name and style name, then it is used. Otherwise, the style name is searched for in the
>   catalog. If it is not found there, an error occurs.
> - For a default style, the external style document is searched to find a `<NamedLayer>` element with the layer name. If it contains a
>   `<UserStyle>` with the `<IsDefault>` element having the value 1 then that
>   style is used. Otherwise, the default server style for the layer
>   (which must exist) is used.

So you either need to provide a named style in the `styles` parameter or make your style a default style by adding `<IsDefault>1</IsDefault>` to it.